# How to Catch a script error in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I have one application having a tab panel, where we can write Extjs code, and By clciking on the button the o/p of the code should display in the preview. For this I have a iFrame and am updating the iframe by document.write(content) method where content is a variable containg the Extjs code.

My requirement is In case there is any error while running the js code , the system shall catch that error and show in the preview area (iframe).

Can anybody have idea how to Catch the errors on Button click ?

I have gone through the w3school try/catch/finally tutorial but it didnt help, as i need to catch the console errors as well.

Thanks
Tapaswini

Comment: could you post your code?  it helps in answering.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Of course we can not achieve this in Extjs. We can achieve this in simple Javascript window.onerror event.

Sample code:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
        var errorbox = document.createElement('div'); 
        errorbox.innerHTML = '<font color = red >'+message+'<br> At line number  :  '+linenumber+'</font>'; 
        document.body.appendChild(errorbox); 
        return ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var varMessage = Ext.MessageBox.show({
    msg: 'Initiating, please wait...',
    //title: 'Please wait',
    progressText: 'Saving...',
    animateTarget: 'btn1',
    progress: true,
    closable: false,
    width: 50,
    wait: true,
    waitConfig: {
        interval: 400,
        duration: 2000,
        //increment: 2,
        text: 'Initiating...',
        scope: this,
        fn: function() {
            //Code for ajax request
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'url',
                async: false,
                //Code for if url successfully done
                success: function(response, opts) {
                    var obj = (response.responseText);
                    Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                    //Code for error handling
                    try {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Request successfully done .');
                    } catch(err) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Some error occured during execution.<br/></br>' + err);
                    } finally {}
                    //Code for error handling
                    },
                //Code for if any error occured during execution
                failure: function(response, opts) {
                    Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Some issue occured during execution on server !");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```